# Centos yum install Transaction check error

Tags: mysql, centos, sphinx, mariadb, yum

I have downloaded and trying to install sphinx in centos 7 using command

```
yum localinstall sphinx-2.2.6-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
```

It shows the dependency mariadb-libs. I have mariadb and mysql already installed and working

While installing dependency mariadb-libs for sphinx, the errors are thrown:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.48-1.cp1148.x86_64
```

Is there will be any problem removing these files and retry install as I think these are language and charset files  that do not cause issues. Or is it better to install with replace files option. Please advice.

Comment: Install in a different place?

Answer (score 0):

there is conflicts between  mariadb-libs and mysql-server rpm package.

because some files will be replace, so yum give warning error.

first of, you can download  mariadb-libs rpm  .  and forced install .eg:rpm -ivh  --force mariadb-libs.xxx.rpm

then  execute you own cmd.

yum localinstall sphinx-2.2.6-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm